# javascript 32bit integer multiply simulation

Tags: javascript

I just want multiply int like 32bit integer with overflow.

some article that is easy to like that with bitwise operation

```
function add32bit( a, b )
{
    return (a+b)|0;
}
```

and like that.

```
function mul32bit( a, b )
{
    return (a*b)|0;
}
```

but it's not work.

in 32bit integer system that allow integer overflow.

calulate

```
12312311 * 1231231211 = -236858179
```

but with javascript

```
(12312311 * 1231231211)|0 = -236858180
```

there is the way calulate extactly.

Comment: Can you show what values you would pass to your function and what result you expect? Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/918094/edit) to show this

Comment: Karatsuba multiplication is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

## Solution (?)

Following the hint from *Richie Frame* I tried to use the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) to program a function that multiplies two integers and returns the result as a signed 32-Bit integer.

```
// base algorithm from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm
// modified to discard values unneccessary for 32-Bit-operations

function int32_mul(x, y)
{
    // We use B = 2 and m = 16, because it will make sure that we only do multiplications with
    // 16 Bit per factor so that the result must have less than 32 Bit in total (which fits well
    // into a double).
    var bm = 1 << 16;

    x0 = x % bm;
    x1 = (x - x0) / bm;

    y0 = y % bm;
    y1 = (y - y0) / bm;

    // z1 + z0. We can discard z2 completely as it only contains a value out of our relevant bounds.
    // Both z1 and z0 are 32 Bit, but we shift out the top 16 Bit of z1.
    return (((x1 * y0 + x0 * y1) << 16) + (x0 * y0)) | 0;
}
```

I've also run some tests to make sure it works, but I'm not a professional on this field and thus I cannot guarantee it's going to work for all combinations. TBH my brain got a bit mushy about this problem.

```
var tests = [
    [ 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 1 << 8, 256 ],
    [ 1, 1 << 16, 65536 ],
    [ 1, 1 << 24, 16777216 ],
    [ 1, 0x7fffffff, 2147483647 ],
    [ 1, 0x80000000, -2147483648 ],
    [ 1, 0xffffffff, -1 ],
    [ 2, 1 << 8, 512 ],
    [ 2, 1 << 16, 131072 ],
    [ 2, 1 << 24, 33554432 ],
    [ 2, 0x80000000, 0 ],
    [ 2, 0x7fffffff, -2 ],
    [ 2, 0xffffffff, -2 ],
    [ 256, 256, 65536 ],
    [ 65536, 65536, 0 ],
    [ -2, 2, -4 ],
    [ -65536, 65536, 0 ],
    [ -2, -2, 4 ],
    [ -2147483648, 1, -2147483648 ],
    [ -2147483649, 1, 2147483647 ],
    [ 12312311, 1231231211, -236858179 ],
];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; ++i)
{
    var test = tests[i];
    if (int32_mul(test[0], test[1]) !== test[2])
    { console.log(test[0], '*', test[1], '!==', test[2]); }
}
```

If someone with more professionalism finds this, please leave a comment and/or enlight us with further test cases.

Also I cannot quite say what kind of values this function accepts. I'm pretty sure it's going to work well with all signed 32-Bit integers, but it may also work with unsigned 32-Bit integers or maybe even any integer combination that doesn't exceed 68 Bits (16 Bits we split off + [52 Bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) in total (both negative and positive, because the sign has an own bit in doubles).

## Problem Explanation

Have an explanation why JavaScript gets us a wrong result. I ran some simple tests using C (fiddle around with it on http://ideone.com/ELSgD0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", (int32_t)(12312311L * 1231231211L));
    printf("%llu\n", (uint64_t)12312311L * 1231231211L);
    printf("%.32f\n", 12312311. * 1231231211.);
    printf("%.8f\n", 15159301582738621.);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-236858179
15159301582738621
15159301582738620.00000000000000000000000000000000
15159301582738620.00000000
```

Javascript uses doubles for all calculations (even integer ones). From the above tests I conclude that a double cannot have the value `15159301582738621`.

This is because of how floating-point datatypes like float (32 Bit), double (64 Bit) and quad (128 Bit) work. Basically they do not store exact values, but rather the `x` and `y` values of a value in the form `x * 2^y`, which enables them to store both very big values and very small ones. We (humans) use to have a similar syntax for very big and small numbers, e.g. `1e9` for one billion or `1e-5` for `0.00001`, whereas the `e` is a shortcut for `* 10^`.

Now say you calculate `10001 * 10001`, which is obviously `100020001`, but imagine you were only able to store 5 digits and one exponent. To store the result, you'd have to approximate it and use e.g. `1.0002e8` or `10002e4`. As you can see you'd have to forget about the 1 at the end. Actually the problem with doubles in your exaple is quite similar, just in a larger scale and base 2 instead of 10.

The last two `printf` statements prove that doubles can't hold the value `15159301582738621`, which is the exact result of your example calculation. If you try it with `12312311 * 1231231212` (2 at the end of the second number instead of 1) you'll see that not all numbers in this range cannot be stored as a double as that calculation works fine with your function.